# pycharm telling me that i installed a package but i cant use that pakege

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0guROQYp9v4&feature=youtu. the youtube video will show a little bit more what the problem is I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pycharm and many other things. nothing seems to work there is no real code I have just been trying to use pyautogui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- wait for `pip` to recover from https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5252
- install all requirements http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
- install `pyautogui`
- fix typo in import: `piautogui` -> `pyautogui`

Comment: I created a ticket in PyCharm bug tracker: [PY-29611](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29611).